# How to increment multiple range/cell references in a function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a function which is capable of having multiple cell refrenece in it so I can reference it some like as follows

```
csvRange(A2,C2:E2,G2)
```

That outputs the cells values, which when dragged down in a column increments the reference to the next row. I've currently got this:

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
Dim csvRangeOutput

For Each entry In myRange
    csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
Next
csvRange = csvRangeOutput
End Function
```

This is fine for one range but not multiples

Also as a curve ball and just for my own application I need be to add this between each cell

```
Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
```

Reason being for this is for a csv application so if I have A1 = Test1 and B1=Test2 in the function the result would be

```
Test1","Test2
```

I do know that excel has an export function for doing this but it wont work for my application

Comment: Ok so apparently, your `For Each` doesn't work? Am I right?
For the start and end of range, you may be able to use `End()` function if your ranges are not contigous (all surrounded by empty cells), what does they look like?

Comment: The For Each does work, for a given range eg information A2:D2 when dragged down. however not all my coloumn are in an order eg I might be using A2,C2,F2 I want to be able to specify this inside my function. Hope this make more sense

Comment: also ive just realised I'm talking rubbish, I dont need to specify the end range so ill scrub this from my question, it's been able to specify certain coloumn or coloumn ranges inside the function I need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you, to be used like this `csvRange("C2:F7;C5:D6")` :

```
Function csvRange(myRange As String) As String
Dim csvRangeOutput As String, _
    AbsAdd As String, _
    ColNum As Double, _
    A() As String
A = Split(myRange, ";")


For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
'    If InStr(1, A(i), ":") Then
        'Range is 1D or 2D
        For Each cel In Range(A(i))
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & cel.Value & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
        Next cel
'    Else
'        'Describe range is a single cell => we scan the whole column
'        AbsAdd = Range("E1").Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
'        ColNum = CDbl(Right(AbsAdd, Len(AbsAdd) - InStr(1, AbsAdd, "C")))
'        For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
'            If cel.Value<>vbNullString then csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & cel.Value & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
'        Next k
'    End If
Next i


csvRange = csvRangeOutput
End Function
```

Comment: maybe its me but I cant get this to work, when I add this into a module and use it in a cell I just get #VALUE "A Value in the data is of the wrong data type" I tried specify it different ways too and still get same error csvRange(A2:C2), csvRange(A2) and csvRange(A2,C2)

Comment: Mhhh... I wasn't absolutely sure of what you wanted to do, but now I'm truly lost... You want to use this function directly in a workbook or in a VBA module? I already wasn't sure about what you meant with the columns, please clarify what you are trying to do so that we can be more accurate in answers.

Comment: I want to use it directly in a worksheet, my current VBA code above does do what I want the problem is I can only use 1 range eg csvRange(A2:C2) But im trying to say is I may need more than 1 range I might need to do this    csvRange(A2:C2,F2,H2:J2) my code can only do the first range

Comment: my original code works, but when i've tried the edit it doesnt work I still get #VALUE doesnt even work if I try csvRange(A2:D2) which works with the orignal code

Comment: Okay I see what is the problem, you just need to put brackets around your selection to convert it to a string so that the function can split it afterwards. Look at the answer, I edited it and switch separator to ";". Function to be used like this : `csvRange("C2:F7;C5:D6")`

Comment: Thankyou for clarify that for us, This works csvRange("C2:F7") for one range but if I try your example csvRange("C2:F7;C5:D6") this doesnt work for two ranges. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to update the code here to change separator to ";", now it is done and it is working for me!

Comment: Cheers R3uK works perfect, sorry for confusion in my question. Thanks for help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77690/discussion-between-windmill-and-r3uk).